# Android PopUp ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, popupwindow

I want to implement in my android application a functionality like when a user clicks a button in header a small list view is popup having 5 values in the corner of the screen. Please give some suggestion, its urgent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean a quick action menu ? Like this ? 
[image]

If so, check this :
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Actually I want a vertical listview, which should be scrollable and when scrolling, a small image should be visible beside the current selected list item so that the user can know which item is selected.

Answer (score 2):

It depends somewhat on the minimum SDK that you are targeting.  If you are able to write your application with a minimum target of Android 3.0 (API Level 11), then there are at least two classes that you can use to accomplish creating a simple popup anchored to another view (in this case, your button):

- [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)
- [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Otherwise, you will need to do a little customization of [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), which is the class that many early QuickAction implementations are based on.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Design a listview inside it RelativeLayout view  in that same layout and make it as invisible. once you click a button at the header you can make it visible. which  shows the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Activity for popup and add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` to Activity node in Manifest file.