# ListView over Gridview (QuickAction Menu)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, popupmenubutton

i am trying to create a layout where on Button Click a listview is to be shown(popup) and it is done
but the main problem is listview makes gridview to slide down and i don't want that.I want 
listview to popup over gridview.
Help how to do it
My codes are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:tag="medium"  
android:id="@+id/test"
android:background="@drawable/background_new" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_new"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apps_Heading"
            style="@style/Heading"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="My Apps"
            /> 

         <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:background="@drawable/home"
   /> 
    </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/listview"
         android:layout_width="80dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
       >
         <ListView 
    android:layout_height="80dp" 
    android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu" 
    android:layout_width="80dp"        
    android:layout_gravity="right"   
    android:layout_below="@+id/menuBtn"    
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
  />                  
                  </RelativeLayout>




    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/MyGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

     menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);

     menuBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
    menuBtn.setOnClickListener(this);       

        menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

                // Note: if the list was built "by hand" the id could be used.
                // As-is, though, each item has the same id

                TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();

                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase("First Section")) {
                    // Launch the Game Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,
        Activity.class));

                } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase("Second Section")) {
                    // Launch the Help Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,
        NameActivity.class));

               } 

                else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase("Fourth Section")) {
                    // Launch the Settings Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,
        Profile.class));

                   // menuList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase("Logout")) {
                    // Launch the Scores Activity
                    LoginscreenCall();

                }
            }
        });

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    globalMenu=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    globalMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String[] option={"First Section", "Second Section", "THird Section", 
            "Fourth Section", "Log Out"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.menu_item, option);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapt);

    if(menuList.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
    {
        menuList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("Menu Button", "Invisible");

    }
    else{
        menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
         menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         Log.e("Menu Button", "Visible");
    }


}
```

Comment: please simplify your question. if you don't want grid view why you code (in xml and in java) for it. and what do you mean by ."I want listview to generate over griview." i am not getting what you want to do.. please be specific.

Comment: thavx for help i got answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who tried to help. I googled and found that i can use Quick Action for my purpose ans link i used for my reference is

[londatiga](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) and [lorensiuswlt](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt).

and i got these answer [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981773/android-popup-listview)
Thank You.

I'll post my used code when i am finished with this.